# Uri pattern to connect to rabbitmq from golang

Tags: go, rabbitmq, connection, uri

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ from golang client using this uri pattern

```
amqp://user:pass@host:10000/vhost:

conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://user1:User!@#@vserver803:5672/vuser")

host: vserver111
port: 5672
username: user1
password: User!@#
virtual-host: vuser
```

the code returns the an error:

```
Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5672: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Though I can connect to the host via telnet.

Comment: Try percent encoding the special characters in the password, they can't be used directly in a URI.

Comment: you have a problem because the password contains `@` symbol (-;
Try to use an URL encoding for the password.

Answer (score -3):

In my experience with rabbitMq i created a POC with Golang. About you problem, maybe you could try with the following connections string.

```
url = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672"
```

Here you have my personal Github account where you can find these POC.

https://github.com/jsperk/poc_rabbit

Regards.